# Is there a way to group selectors?

Tags: css, less

I'm trying to address all the `div`, `table`, `ul`, `dl`, etc. children of a selector using LESS.

I would love to write something like this.

```
.myclass {
  ...

  &.otherClass > (div, ul, dl, table) {
    // define some rules...
  }
}
```

I would expect the following output.

```
.myclass.otherClass > div,
.myclass.otherClass > ul,
.myclass.otherClass > dl,
.myclass.otherClass > table {
  // rules
}
```

But the parenthesis seems like not supported, as it compiles as is, resulting an invalid CSS of course.

Is there any syntax or other way to have such a shortcut in definitions?

Comment: Is it all children or just a few selected tag types? ... or maybe all but one tag type?

Comment: Just these tags which I enumerated in the post.

Comment: Asked as you could do `.myclass.otherClass > * { ... }` or maybe `.myclass.otherClass > :not(li) { ... }` which might give you shorter code

Comment: Yes, I know about these options, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution:

```
.myclass {
  ...

  &.otherClass {
    > div, > ul, > dl, > table {
         // define some rules...
    }
  }
}
```

---

As for your comment, removing the `>` selector after the first selector, will produce a different result:

**This example**

```
div {
    > span, p, a {
     border:1px solid #333;
    }
}
```

compiles into

```
div > span, div p, div a {
    border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

**while this example**

```
div {
    > span, > p, > a {
     border:1px solid #333;
    }
}
```

compiles into

```
div > span, div > p, div > a {
    border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

Comment: Ok, so basically there is no way to group things like I wanted, and the shortest syntax is to nest another level. I'll accept your answer though, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution similar to randy's answer is use a variable for `.otherClass` and `>`:

```
@selector: .otherClass >;

.myclass {
  display:block;
  &@{selector} {
    div, ul, dl, table {
      color:red
    }
  }
}
```